# Dynamically build multiple expressions

Tags: r, dynamic, expression, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I want to use the `microbenchmark` function to time expressions, but some of them need to be created dynamically (at run-time).

It looks like I need to use `bquote` `as.call` and `Reduce` ([Dynamically creating functions and expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379020/dynamically-creating-functions-and-expressions)) but I have never used them and the author doesn't explain what he's doing in detail, making it hard to understand what is happening.

Here is what I would like to do (very simplified):

```r
library(microbenchmark)

# random number of benchmarks
n <- rpois(n = 1, lambda = 5)

# random names
expressions <- LETTERS[rpois(n = n, lambda = 10)]

# random parameters
times <- runif(n = n, max = 1e-5)

microbenchmark(
  expressions[1] = Sys.sleep(times[1]),
  expressions[2] = Sys.sleep(times[2]),
  ...
  expressions[n] = Sys.sleep(times[n])
)
```

I understand asking others to do everything is discouraged, so can anyone at least tell me where I should start?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically build a function call where you change parameter names, you'll need to build a named list where the names of the list are the parameter names. You'll also need to delay evaluation of your parameters so you'll want to pass language object. There are bunch of different ways to do that but in this case `bquote()` is probably most helpful. So for example

```
set.seed(15)
n <- rpois(n = 1, lambda = 5)
expressions <- LETTERS[rpois(n = n, lambda = 10)]
times <- runif(n = n, max = 1e-5)

params <- setNames(
  lapply(times, function(x) bquote(Sys.sleep(.(x)))),
  expressions)
params
# $G
# Sys.sleep(7.06628567539156e-06)
# $H
# Sys.sleep(8.62313656602055e-06)
# $L
# Sys.sleep(8.41785145225003e-06)
# $K
# Sys.sleep(4.47443719021976e-06)
# $F
# Sys.sleep(9.64666954241693e-06)
```

Once you have this named list of expressions, you can call `microbenchmark` using the `do.call` function to turn your list of parameters into actual parameters.

```
do.call("microbenchmark", params)
#  expr min  lq mean median  uq   max neval
#     G 200 300  312    300 300  1600   100
#     H 200 200  478    300 300 19100   100
#     L 200 250  288    300 300   500   100
#     K 200 200  284    300 300   700   100
#     F 200 300  300    300 300  1700   100
```